# How to add day information into the month field using biblatex

Tags: biblatex

Is it possible to add some information about the day of publication in biblatex? Is it also possible to make double month entries with biblatex?

The bibtex entries

```
month=mar#"/"#apr,
month=mar#"15"
```

do fine with bibtex, but they don't work with biblatex.

Comment: Please note that you can format source-code blocks by adding 4 whitespaces in front of each line, or simply selecting it and clicking the "code" `{}` button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fot the day of publication you can use the `date` field. A date can be specified `YYYY-MM-DD` or using a date range `YYYY-MM-DD/YYYY-MM-DD` months and days are optional.

For the other issues, how to specify double month entires, the best option is to use either `issue` or `number`. Here are the relevant extracts from the `biblatex` manual:

> `issues` (literal) 
>   The issue of a journal. This field is intended for journals whose individual issues are identified by a designation such as ‘Spring’ or ‘Summer’ rather than the month or a number. Since the placement of issue is similar to month and number, this field may also be useful with double issues and other special cases. See also `month`, `number`, and § 2.3.9.
>
> `month` (integer) 
>   The publication month. This must be an integer, not an ordinal or a string. Don’t say `month={January}` but `month={1}`. The bibliography style converts this to a language dependent string or ordinal where required. See also date as well as §§ 2.3.9 and 2.3.8.
>
> `number` (literal) 
>   The number of a journal or the volume/number of a book in a series. See also issue as well as §§ 2.3.7 and 2.3.9. With `@patent` entries, this is the number or record token of a patent or patent request.

**EDIT**

When `biblatex` is used with biber, then one can use the `\DeclareSourcemap` feature to "transform" the entries and the field in a `.bib` file in place. Here is a definition of  the source map for the given format of month.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=month,
        match=\regexp{\d\d/\d\d},
        fieldset=number, origfieldval]
      \step[fieldsource=month,
        match=\regexp{(\d\d)\s*(\d+)},
        fieldset=day, fieldvalue={$2}]
      \step[fieldsource=month,
        match=\regexp{(\d\d)\d*}, replace=\regexp{$1}]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks the quick answer. With the 'date'-field it works as intended, but it is still a slow workaround, because the most citations I use come from databases with bibtex-style-entries, so I have to change each citation manually. It takes a lot of time to rebuild a list of 100 citations.

Comment: You can use the sourcemap features of biber to automate that. Do you have the data in the `month` field? and is the format the one in the question?

Comment: All tha data is in the 'month'-field and has the structure, given above

month=mar#"/"#apr,
month=mar#"15" or
month=mar.

There is no 'date'-field in the original bibtex-files.

Comment: @ddi revised the definition of `\DeclareSourcemap` according  to the given format.